# Translating spark dataframe aggregations to SQL query; problems with window, groupby, and how to aggregate?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I'm messing around with the data from Spark: The Definitive Guide and am using Java just for purposes of well-roundedness.

I'm reading the data in fine from a CSV and creating a temporary view table like so:

```
Dataset<Row> staticDataFrame = spark.read().format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load("/data/retail-data/by-day/*.csv");

staticDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("SalesInfo");

spark.sql("SELECT CustomerID, (UnitPrice * Quantity) AS total_cost, InvoiceDate from SalesInfo").show(10);
```

This works fine and returns the following data:

```
+----------+------------------+--------------------+
|CustomerID|        total_cost|         InvoiceDate|
+----------+------------------+--------------------+
|   14075.0|             85.92|2011-12-05 08:38:...|
|   14075.0|              25.0|2011-12-05 08:38:...|
|   14075.0|39.599999999999994|2011-12-05 08:38:...|
|   14075.0|              30.0|2011-12-05 08:38:...|
|   14075.0|15.299999999999999|2011-12-05 08:38:...|
|   14075.0|              40.8|2011-12-05 08:38:...|
|   14075.0|              39.6|2011-12-05 08:38:...|
|   14075.0|             40.56|2011-12-05 08:38:...|
|   18180.0|              17.0|2011-12-05 08:39:...|
|   18180.0|              17.0|2011-12-05 08:39:...|
+----------+------------------+--------------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

I'm having problems when I try to group it by CustomerID, however when I try to group it by CustomerID,

```
spark.sql("SELECT CustomerID, (UnitPrice * Quantity) AS total_cost, InvoiceDate from SalesInfo GROUP BY CustomerID").show(10);
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'salesinfo.`UnitPrice`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.
```

I get the notion of what I'm doing wrong, namely that it doesn't know how to aggregate total_cost and invoice date, but I'm stuck on how to do that in terms of SQL; the book uses spark aggregation functions and does this:

```
selectExpr(
"CustomerId",
"(UnitPrice * Quantity) as total_cost",
"InvoiceDate")
```

.groupBy(
    col("CustomerId"), window(col("InvoiceDate"), "1 day"))
  .sum("total_cost")

But I'm trying to understand how I can do that with SQL statements as a learning exercise.

Any help on how to do this via query is appreciated.

I am trying to figure out how to do it where I just get grand totals per customer ID but then how to get the full functionality of the book's spark statement, where it's the total amount broken out into hours by the customer ID.

Thank you

EDIT: This is the source of the data; I'm just reading it all in to one dataset

https://github.com/databricks/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/tree/master/data/retail-data/by-day

Comment: Have you got a link to the data somewhere so that we could import it to try and reproduce what you're doing?

Comment: Good idea, I'll add it from the author's site

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm interpreting what you're saying as UnitPrice * Quantity per customer, per hour, in SQL:

```
select 
    customerid, 
    sum(unitprice * quantity) as total_cost, 
    cast(cast(InvoiceDate as date) as varchar) + ' ' + cast(DATEPART(HH, InvoiceDate) as varchar) + ':00'
from [retail-data] 
group by CustomerID, cast(cast(InvoiceDate as date) as varchar) + ' ' + cast(DATEPART(HH, InvoiceDate) as varchar) + ':00'
```

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
DataType varchar is not supported.(line 1, pos 94)

Answer (score 0):

To complete  Geoff Hacker's answer, you can use `explain(true)` method on your DataFrame object to see the execution plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[CustomerId#16, window#41], functions=    [sum(total_cost#26)], output=[CustomerId#16, window#41, sum(total_cost)#35])
  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(CustomerId#16, window#41, 200)
    +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[CustomerId#16, window#41], functions=[partial_sum(total_cost#26)], output=[CustomerId#16, window#41, sum#43])
      +- *(1) Project [named_struct(start,     precisetimestampconversion(((((CASE WHEN     (cast(CEIL((cast((precisetimestampconversion(InvoiceDate#14, TimestampType,     LongType) - 0) as double) / 8.64E10)) as double) =     (cast((precisetimestampconversion(InvoiceDate#14, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) as double) / 8.64E10)) THEN (CEIL((cast((precisetimestampconversion(InvoiceDate#14, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) as double) / 8.64E10)) + 1) ELSE CEIL((cast((precisetimestampconversion(InvoiceDate#14, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) as double) / 8.64E10)) END + 0) - 1) * 86400000000) + 0), LongType, TimestampType), end, precisetimestampconversion(((((CASE WHEN (cast(CEIL((cast((precisetimestampconversion(InvoiceDate#14, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) as double) / 8.64E10)) as double) = (cast((precisetimestampconversion(InvoiceDate#14, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) as double) / 8.64E10)) THEN (CEIL((cast((precisetimestampconversion(InvoiceDate#14, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) as double) / 8.64E10)) + 1) ELSE CEIL((cast((precisetimestampconversion(InvoiceDate#14, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) as double) / 8.64E10)) END + 0) - 1) * 86400000000) + 86400000000), LongType, TimestampType)) AS window#41, CustomerId#16, (UnitPrice#15 * cast(Quantity#13 as double)) AS total_cost#26]
     +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(InvoiceDate#14)
        +- *(1) FileScan csv [Quantity#13,InvoiceDate#14,UnitPrice#15,CustomerID#16] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/tmp/spark/retail/2010-12-01.csv, file:/tmp/spar..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(InvoiceDate)], ReadSchema: struct<Quantity:int,InvoiceDate:timestamp,UnitPrice:double,CustomerID:double>
```

As you see, Spark creates an aggregation key from CustomerId and window (00:00:00 - 23:59:59 for each day) [`HashAggregate(keys=[CustomerId#16, window#41]`] and moves all rows with such keys into a single partition (`Exchange hashpartitioning`). This fact of moving data between partitions is known as shuffle operation. Later it executes SUM(...) function on such accumulated data.

That said, GROUP BY expression with 1 key should generate only 1 row for this key. Thus, if in your initial query you defined CustomerID as the key and total_cost with InvoiceDate in the projection, the engine won't be able to get 1 row for CustomerID since 1 CustomerID can have multiple InvoiceDates. There is no exception regarding SQL language.